# Regular express to match non .com/.net domains?

Tags: php, regex

We're trying to match any domain other than .com and .net. And want to still get a match if the user lists a / or adds spaces after the domain name. For example bit.ly bit.ly/123 and bit.ly(spaces) should all match.

We've tried:

> .[a-z][a-z]$'

But this doesn't show a match when any spaces or characters are after the domain name.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: The requirements are not 100% clear but you could start with something like `\.[a-z]{2}(?:\/\w*)?\s*$`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vzzSPq/1

Comment: `\.(?!com|net)[a-z]+$`

Comment: This is for a chat script we are using. It is PHP based. They support regex in their matching they say.

Comment: Have a try with [that](https://regex101.com/r/Qna1B0/1), does it work for you?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed if you submit that as answer, will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use:

```
https?://\S+?\.(?!com|net)[a-z]+(?:\s|/|$)
```

**Code:**

```
if (preg_match('~https?://\S+?\.(?!com|net)[a-z]+(?:\s|/|$)~')){
    echo "Valid";
}
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Qna1B0/2)

Comment: Is there anyway to adjust this to match http:// or https:// before the match? It appears as though our implementation of this is catching non domain text.
So for example it is catching sentences that people entering without a space:
Hi.there how are you?